# RuntimeError: dispatcher functions can only use None for default argument values

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, spyder, dispatcher, anaconda3

> `runfile('E:/sow/New folder/local.py', wdir='E:/sow/New folder')
> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "E:\sow\New folder\local.py", line 5, in 
> import numpy as np

> File "C:\Users\new\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py", line 140, in 
> from . import core

> File "C:\Users\new\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core_*init*_.py", line 82, in 
> from . import function_base

> File "C:\Users\new\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 24, in 
> def linspace(start, stop, num=None, endpoint=True, retstep=False, dtype=None,

> File "C:\Users\new\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 172, in decorator
> verify_matching_signatures(implementation, dispatcher)

> File "C:\Users\new\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 106, in verify_matching_signatures
> raise RuntimeError('dispatcher functions can only use None for '

> RuntimeError: dispatcher functions can only use None for default argument values`

[Snipshot of error in Anaconda Spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmL2s.png)

Error description=>RuntimeError: dispatcher functions can only use None for default argument values
in spyder console.

Encountered same error for all programs which I had executed in a virtual environment in spyder console

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) It seems you installed some packages with pip which are interfering with the ones provided by Anaconda. However, the solution to this is simple: you need to go to the `C:\Users\new\AppData\Roaming` directory (using the Windows file explorer) and then remove the directory called `Python` in it. That should solve your problem.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thank you so much for your response. The problem has now been resolved and all is well now.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you can work with Numpy without problems now.